# How to find the PMF of a random variable given it's PGF

Tags: probability

How do I go about finding the pmf of a discrete positive random variable X if its pgf is =1/3 (z + z$^2$ + z$^3$)?

Answer (score 0):

Consider that your PGF is, by definition,

$$\mathbb{E}[z^X]$$

Thus $X$ takes the values $\{1;2;3\}$, each value with probability $\frac{1}{3}$